# Selenium cannot select dropdown on span element

Tags: java, selenium

To get the element I have used a nested loop.I am able to click on dropdwn.PFB the code:

```
List<WebElement> webElements1 = driver.findElements(By.className("selectboxit"));

for(WebElement webElement1 : webElements1) {             

 if( webElement1.getAttribute("name").equals("TransactionHistoryFG.OUTFORMAT"))

 {           
    WebElement web1 = webElement1.findElement(By.className("selectboxit-text"));

     web1.click();       
 }
}
```

When i am trying to use Select on webelement  i am getting error :

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element
>   should have been "select" but was "span"

How can i select dropdown i span element?

Comment: As the error states.. You can use Select API only if the given element's tag is Select..i.e if the combo box is a traditional combo box and not a widget combo box.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for selecting dropdown using selenium webdriver is:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//path_to_drop_down")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("Value1");
```

Instead of the approach you mentioned above, let me know if this helps :)

Comment: No ranjith..As i mentioned in the question i already tried select ..its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> webElements1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelect(".selectboxit"));

for(WebElement webElement1 : webElements1) {             

 if( webElement1.getAttribute("name").equals("TransactionHistoryFG.OUTFORMAT"))

 {           
    WebElement web1 = webElement1.findElement(By.className("selectboxit-text"));

     JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", web1);       
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not the best way to do it, but in some cases it can be used:

> it will open your combobox

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelect(".selectboxit")).click()
```

> now, you just need to write the specified value

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelect(".selectboxit")).sendKeys("<value>");
```

> OR

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelect(".selectboxit")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).
```

Use "ARROW_DOWN" as wanted to select your specified value.